# Qual a utilidade do NotMapped?

Tags: c#, dataannotations

Eu gostaria de saber para que serve o `[NotMapped]` e quando devo utiliza-lo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando estamos criando uma aplicação utilizando o *ORM Entity Framework*, podemos utilizar a abordagem *Code First* em que modelamos a aplicação e a partir dela será gerado nosso banco de dados.

Para modelarmos as tabelas da nossa base de dados, nós podemos criar classes no *C#* utilizando os *DataAnnotations*, assim, definindo chave primária, tamanho máximo, constraints, etc.

O atributo `NotMapped` tem a função de dizer que aquela propriedade que possui esse atributo não será mapeada para a tabela, ou seja, não irá conter esse campo na nossa tabela. Então por qual motivo precisamos disso? Simples, as vezes precisamos persistir alguma informação importante para nossa aplicação, mas que não precisa ser salva na base de dados.

Um exemplo, vamos supor que precisamos da idade de uma pessoa, nós já possuímos a data de nascimento persistida no banco, então não precisamos salvar a idade (seria apenas uma informação a mais salva de forma desnecessária), por isso podemos fazer essa lógica em memória:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Idade
    {
        get
        {
             if (DateTime.Now.Month >= DataNascimento.Month && DateTime.Now.Day >= DataNascimento.Day)
                 return DateTime.Now.Year - DataNascimento.Year;

             return DateTime.Now.Year - DataNascimento.Year - 1;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool MaioridadeCivil
    {
        get
        {
            return Idade >= 18;
        }
    }
}
```

Agora sempre que tivermos uma entidade `Pessoa` em mãos nós possuímos a idade e a informação se ela possui maioridade civil em memória e não temos que persistir mais uma informação na base de dados.

Para mais informações, curiosidades ou dúvidas sobre o conteúdo do *Entity Framework*, dê uma conferida nesse link: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Isso é usado na metodologia de Code First do Entity Framework onde você modela uma classe com as propriedades que ela deve ter e ela é transformada em uma tabela com as colunas descritas nessa classe e o banco de dados é criado. Algumas dessas propriedades podem ser interessantes ter só na memória, pode fazer parte do mecanismo que você tem na aplicação, mas não faz parte do modelo, não deve ser persistindo na tabela, pode ser só algo auxiliar, até mesmo algo calculado. Você precisa de algo que expressa que a propriedade não deve ser mapeada para uma coluna na tabela do banco de dados e isso é resolvido com o atributo [`NotMapped`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Vamos dizer que você tenha uma propriedade de data de nascimento e ela é persistida. Você quer ter uma propriedade facilitadora que te entregue a idade, mas ela não precisa ser persistida, você consegue seu valor calculando a data do nascimento com a data atual, você só quer ela na classe. Obviamente que ela não terá um valor, só um cálculo, mas nada impede que tenha um valor, só entenda que ele não será persistido.

Até mesmo uma classe pode ser anotada assim, então toda a classe não se transformará em uma tabela.

Respondi uma pergunta onde este atributo é usado e um código foi escrito na aplicação para lidar com ele:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var c in GetColumns()) WriteLine(c);
    }
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetColumns() => typeof(Usuario).GetProperties()
            .Where(e => e.Name != "Id" && !(Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(e, typeof(NotMappedAttribute)) is NotMappedAttribute))
            .Select(e => e.Name);
}

public class Usuario
{
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lJUoUG). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/un0yzQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/FilterProperties.cs).